# how to restrict changing of number only from last digit

Tags: angularjs, html, validation, input-type-range

I have entered 123 in text box which has a max length of 1000. The problem is that the user is entering 2 by placing cursor at 1 in 123. So the number is displayed as 212 there by pushing 3 somewhere else. I need some help, so that when a user wants to edit the text, he should be doing it from the last digit (deleting last digit then only).

Comment: Could you please post a sample code so we can see where your problem is?

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you want to say user should be able to enter number only in last...no where else?

Comment: hi sorry for delay
as Nishi says i need it 
i want it such that even if user clicks on existing Text the cursor should go back to Last Number 
Example
if the Text Box is 1234 if user places cursor before 1 then cursor should come back After 4 and if user places cursor at 2 or 3 it should come back at last digit
please help me